# Are multiple # allowed in MQTT topics?

Tags: mqtt

Is it allowed to use multiple `#` in MQTT topics ?

For example:

> sensors/data/#/something/else/#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

The MQTT spec ([v3](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718107) and [v5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901242)) says a topic can only use the '#` once in a topic and it must be at the end. e.g.

```
sensor/data/foo/#
```

There is a second wildcard character which is `+`. This can be used anywhere in the topic (between `/`) and matches a single level of topic. e.g.

```
sensor/+/foo/+/json
```

This will match:

```
sensor/1/foo/temp/json
sensor/2/foo/humidity/json
```

but will not match:

```
sensor/1/bar/temp/json
```

or

```
sensor/+/+/data
```

which would match:

```
sensor/foo/bar/data
```

but not:

```
sensor/foo/bar/baz/data
```

You can also combine both e.g.

```
sensor/+/bar/#
```

which would match:

```
sensor/foo/bar/baz/wibble/json
sensor/bar/bar/black/sheep
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. 
The `#` is only allowed at the end.

For more information: [MQTT Topics & Best Practices](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/)